# Pull Facebook status feed and parse with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, status

Hey I'm having trouble finding documentation on pulling Facebook status updates from the public domain. I tried using the Old REST API and the Graph API, and I've hunted for documentation, sample code, tutorials and forums for something just to start me off, but I can't find anything.  All I want to do is grab status feeds from users.  I also saw you could do that by pulling from the RSS feeds, but I think FB shut that down.

This is the closest I got to anything (which came from sample code from another post). I tried substituting in other usernames for "haanmc" but none of the other ones worked:

```
 <?php

 require '../src/facebook.php';
 // Create our Application instance.

 $facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => 'XXXXXX','secret' => 'XXXXX'));
 // This call will always work since we are fetching public data.
 // this could be /username or /username/friends etc...
 // see developer api for FQL for examples
 $status = $facebook->api('/haanmc/feed?limit=1');
 ?>

 <p><?php print $status['data'][0]['message']; ?></p>
 <textarea style="width: 95%; height: 100%;"><?php print_r($status); ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Try a user id number instead of a username.  That "username" isn't actually a username like "John Smith" -- since there are many people so named.  See also: http://graph.facebook.com/haanmc/feed or http://graph.facebook.com/21596019485/feed

Comment: It looks like http://www.facebook.com/haanmc points not to a fb user, but to a group page for a company..might that have something to do with this?  Does your script work for another group? Try it with playdom, a la http://www.facebook.com/Playdom

Comment: Yeah you're right, it does look like a group page, and it works only for group pages which is weird.  I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you want the [Search API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#searching)